# how to store hour and minute in database table while using mktime() function?

Tags: php

I am using a form to get the hour and minute using post method and then store it to mysql DB.

Such as :

```
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minute = $_POST['minute'];
```

** There is no need of date, month and year. I just need to store the hour and minute in a column of a table (ex: exam_time)

Column structure: **exam_time time NOT NULL**

Now how to store these value into database using mktime() function. I tried but it stores 00:00:00, not the one which I am sending via form.

Comment: Please also include how you use mktime() and your SQL query.

Comment: How are you using `mktime`? What exactly are you trying to store in the database?

Comment: may be `$exam_time = $hour.':'.$minute.':'.'00' ;`

Comment: I use $exam_time = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, 0, 0, 0);
and then the sql is

INSERT INTO exam_schedule (exam_time) VALUES ($exam_time)

Comment: mktime gives you timestamp and your field datatype is time

Comment: You have to go with one of tow approach, first is what @GDB mentioned above, Second is to store time as UNIX TIMESTAMP with complete date like: yyyy/mm/dd hh:ii:ss by only this way mktime will do the job.

Comment: Concatenate the hour and minute, then validate it with this before inserting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005728/php-validating-24-hour-time-format

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the purpose of `mktime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php.

`mktime` returns an integer value representing the unix timestamp.

If you need to store a time value, use `date` or `getdate` functions to format the input to the required values.

Comment: "mktime returns an integer value representing the unix timestamp" --- now i understand and my problem is solved. 

I set my MySQL column into int(11) and then it stores the actual value in timestamp format. BTW My problem is solved, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`mktime()`, `date()`, `getdate()` all handle UNIX timestamps.

In your case you have two separate fields for hour and time.
The TIME column in mySQL does not handle UNIX timestamps, so you shouldn't use the functions above.

**The range is ‘-838:59:59’ to ‘838:59:59’. MySQL displays TIME values in ‘HH:MM:SS’ format, but allows you to assign values to TIME columns using either strings or numbers**

So, according to this, you could try to insert a new time value like this:

```
"INSERT INTO mytable ( exam_time ) VALUES ( '" . $hour . ":" . $minute . "' )"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the script is correct, however you've set your MySQL column to `DATE` rather than `DATETIME`?

Comment: I set my MySQL column into int(11) and then it stores the actual value in timestamp format. BTW My problem is solved, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use TIME_ZONE_SET (your zone) then insert (hours, minits)into exam_time VALUES (" '.date("H").' ", "'.date("i").'") using the DATETIME SELECTED IN YOUR MYSQL DATABASE.